# azure - how to integrate azure advanced App Service Authentication / Authorization to access azure devops API (tasks, pipelines)

Tags: azure, azure-devops-rest-api

Building a webpage to show list of azuredevops tasks, pipelines.. the page would be authenticated with AAD login. so to get the info of devops (tasks) from api, how it needs to be authenticated and how we can implement this.

Answer (score 0):

If your application type is `Interactive client-side` or `Interactive JavaScript`, you can use the `Active Directory authentication library` ([ADAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries)) authentication mechanism. You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#authenticate) and [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/authentication-guidance?view=azure-devops):

[image]

The ADAL enables application developers to authenticate users to cloud or on-premises Active Directory (AD), and obtain tokens for securing API calls.ADAL makes authentication easier for developers through features such as:

- Configurable token cache that stores access tokens and refresh tokens
- Automatic token refresh when an access token expires and a refresh
  token is available
- Support for asynchronous method calls

Comment: Do agree! For interactive client side ADAL library the best choice. The scenario here using the advanced authentication / authorisation of azure (/.auth/login/done) the request are authenticated and every request w’ll provide principal and aad token - do the same token valid for devops api (to read task, build) will it need to any setting  changes or need to re-authenticate with devops again!

Comment: It does not need to re-authenticate again.If this answer is helpful to you, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Have a nice day.

Comment: There anything needs to be added like allow token audience in advance section of authentication / authorisation tab

Comment: I'm not familiar with this.If you have gained any experience from the test,welcome to share it here.